# list index out of bounds for not the obvious reason numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm not sure why but I keep getting this error, even though the list index does not exceed the number of indexes. The code getting this error is below:

```
    normalisedFaces = np.array([])
    for f in range(len(vertextNormalIndices)):
        nF1 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndices[f][0][0]]
        nF2 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndices[f][1][0]]
        nF3 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndices[f][2][0]]
        normalisedFaces = np.hstack((normalisedFaces,(np.add(nF1,np.add(nF2,nF3))/ 3)))
        print(f)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(normalisedFaces[f])
```

My only guess is that I'm reaching the end of the max size of an array(?) For this example, the loop has the range of 529 , but the error comes up when I reach  519. If I change the loop to something like:

```
    for f in range(len(vertextNormalIndices)-200):
```

Then it reaches the end of the range (so, in this case: 329).

How would one go about fixing this? If possible, I'd prefer not to have to nest this loop and have to split-up the size of each array to e.g. %max==300

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

I've attached a screenshot of the error here:
[image]

**The last 8 indexes of vertexNormalIndices:** (So, gets the first number of each row e.g. 278, 195, 281)

[image]

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback and some example input data?

Comment: for some background, 'vertextNormalIndices' is a numpy array filled with the 'Faces' of a wavefront .obj file. It look something like:
 [ [ [10,10,10] , [16,16,16] , [13,13,13] ] , [[..],[..],[..]], ...  ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comments, and looking at your traceback, the error is in this line:
`nF1 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndices[f][0][0]]`

So, the error *must* be that either `vertextNormalIndices[519]`  or `vertextNormalIndices[519][0]` is an empty list - try printing them out in the loop.

As an aside:

The 'Pythonic' way to iterate through a list is to do it directly, and if you also need to get the index of each element, you should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
normalisedFaces = np.array([])
for f, vertexNormalIndex in enumerate(vertextNormalIndices):
    nF1 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndex[0][0]]
    nF2 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndex[1][0]]
    nF3 = vecNormals[vertextNormalIndex[2][0]]
    normalisedFaces = np.hstack((normalisedFaces,(np.add(nF1,np.add(nF2,nF3))/ 3)))
    print(f)
time.sleep(3)
print(normalisedFaces[f])
```

Comment: as mentioned above,   
it's the last 10 elements, that aren't in the loop. So I reach only 519 / 529

Comment: it was the vertextNormalIndices -.- I noticed the object file was referencing vector normals starting with an index of 1. So it was just coincidence I reached 519/ 529, where this has a value of a vector normal that has an index of one-above the size; could've just of easily reached 1/529 and failed. Thanks

Comment: it was these lines: (for all three)

nF1 = vecNormals[(vertextNormalIndices[f][0][0]-1)]

Comment: No you will not... `range(3)` is `[0, 1, 2]`, so doing `for i in range(len(x)): x[i]`, while not the most Pythonic of things, will work no problem.

Comment: @Jaime. What was I thinking?? Thank you for correcting me.